# Scale and fit GeoJSON to the SVG map with d3-geo

Tags: javascript, d3

I am trying to follow the excellent tutorial by Mike Bostock on [medium](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-1-face) with my own data.

Instead of a GeoJSON of California, I am trying to fit a small parcel somewhere in Norway to the map.

My input GeoJSON file is [here](https://pastebin.com/j5MN7AjA), and looks like this:

[image: GeoJSON file from parcel]

Instead of using geproject to California Albers, I thought it would be better to use Transverse Mercator:

> geoproject 'd3.geoTransverseMercator().fitSize([960, 960], d)' < se.json > se-transverse.json

The result of the project is [[here][4](https://pastebin.com/dqycpiAA)](https://pastebin.com/dqycpiAA), and it gave me the result I was hoping and expecting; all coordinates within the fitSize([960, 960] size. I am now wondering what I am missing to map this to scale. The resulting SVG I am getting after doing

> geo2svg < se-transverse.json > se-transverse.svg

is:

[image]

Which is just a tiny dot. It's the polygon, but not at scale. I thought the fitsize parameter fixed this, but there must be something else I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to me not knowing that the GeoJSON file needed to be in the reverse winding order.

My solution was to do install geojson-rewind and reverse the GeoJSON file.

> npm install --save @mapbox/geojson-rewind

There is an option --counterclockwise in this tool that needed to be turned on, even though it makes the file clockwise (https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-rewind/issues/1#issuecomment-577174363)

Philippe Rivière at visionscarto.net was helping with this problem:

## download

curl https://pastebin.com/raw/j5MN7AjA > ./original.geojson

## follows GeoJSON spec

geojson-rewind original.geojson > ccw.geojson

## this won't work: D3 expects clockwise polygons

geoproject 'd3.geoTransverseMercator().fitSize([960, 500], d)' < ccw.geojson > ccw-projected.json

geo2svg --fill red ccw-projected.json > ccw.svg

## d3-compatible

## note that the --counterclockwise option creates clockwise polygons

geojson-rewind --counterclockwise original.geojson > cw.geojson

geoproject 'd3.geoTransverseMercator().fitSize([960, 500], d)' < cw.geojson > cw-projected.json

geo2svg --fill green cw-projected.json > cw.svg